# Liquibase running when contextLoads test in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase

When i run my spring boot contextLoads test, the code broken becouse liquibase is trying running

```
Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP
```

my pom just has the property

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
  <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

how should i do to my liquibase stop running in the test context?

Thanks.

Comment: For your test environment you can use spring.liquibase.enabled=false

Comment: @abhinavxeon how can i do that? i just used 
```
@TestPropertySource(properties = "spring.liquibase.enabled=false")
@SpringBootTest
class PismoInterviewProjectApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```
and didn`t works

Answer (score 0):

You can disable `liquibase` with property `spring.liquibase.enabled=false`.
If you are using @SpringBootTest you can add properties to it.

```
@SpringBootTest(properties = { "spring.liquibase.enabled=false" })
```

Comment: now i hav Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' problem, i think theres and config to disable this too, right?

Comment: You can mock entityManagerFactory.